# Sync two mysql db, but not all rows via cron php script

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron, synchronization

I have a database that needs to sync to another but not all the rows inside the db.

I have just wasted money and time posting a project on freelancer as the project winner wanted to edit the files of the site that drives the DB but was unable to as they are encrypted.

I need 2 databases to sync excluding one (table/row)

For example:

```
1 <-> 1
2 <-> 2
3 <-> 3
4 <-> 4
5 <-> 5
6 no 6
```

I would like it to be run by a cron job both database be on the same server

I'm asking not for a solution, but a better way to write this project as I'm not clued up in all the jargon.

Even if it's possible, how much work would it be?

Comment: I would say the term you are looking for is "partial replication".  You can do replication with MySQL.  Don't re-invent the wheel though. Replication is a hard problem if you tried to do it on your own. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html  You don't need a cron job to do this because MySQL will manage it for you.

Comment: would you mind re writing what i wrote so people would understand what i am after regarding this project? also thanks for the reply:)

Comment: You have two databases on the same server.  You want some tables (maybe not all) to replicate from database A to database B.  For some tables, you want to be able to set criteria for which rows are replicated.  (I'm not sure if you can do this by the way.)  The databases are MySQL so you want to use the default, out of the box MySQL replication.